# Kotlin - Restrict extension method scope

Tags: scope, dsl, kotlin

Is there a way to restrict extension methods in DSLs?

Say I have a class structure like this:

```
class Outer {
    fun middle(op: Middle.() -> Unit): Middle {
        val middle = Middle()
        middle.op()
        return middle
    }
}

class Middle {
    fun inner(op: Inner.() -> Unit): Inner {
        val inner = Inner()
        inner.op()
        return inner
    }
}

class Inner

fun outer(op: Outer.() -> Unit): Outer {
    val outer = Outer()
    outer.op()
    return outer
}
```

I can then create a call like so:

```
outer {
    middle {
        inner {
            middle { }  // Here is the problem
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that the marked `middle { }` call is confusing, as it adds a `Middle` to the `Outer` when it looks like it is adding to the `Inner`.

Is there a way to not allow the `middle { }` call?

Comment: This is currently not possible but it's planned for 1.1 according to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11551

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a workaround with `deprecated`:

```
class Outer {
    fun middle(op: Middle.() -> Unit): Middle {...}

    @Deprecated("can not be used inside a Outer block", level = DeprecationLevel.ERROR)
    fun outer(op: Outer.() -> Unit): Outer = TODO()
}

class Middle {
    fun inner(op: Inner.() -> Unit): Inner {...}

    @Deprecated("can not be used inside a Middle block", level = DeprecationLevel.ERROR)
    fun middle(op: Middle.() -> Unit): Middle = TODO()
}

class Inner {
    @Deprecated("can not be used inside a Inner block", level = DeprecationLevel.ERROR)
    fun inner(op: Inner.() -> Unit): Inner = TODO()
}
```

Now the compiler will give you an error, and IDE will not suggest a wrong function in the completion:

```
outer {
    middle {
        inner {
            middle { }  // error
        }
    }
}
```

<s>But you really should not do it for big DSLs. It is better to wait for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11551 as @KirillRakhman suggested.</s>

**Edit:** After I fixed my example, it became much smaller. With one dummy function for a class it is not that much of boilerplate after all.

Comment: @KirillRakhman please see the edit. Now for n classes it is only n dummy functions, not (n^2)/2. And thanks to the `level` parameter those deprecations are not warnings, but errors. With that I fail to see any benefit of a language level feature for that use case like in KT-11551

Answer (score 4):

The official way to restrict scope is [DslMarker](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-dsl-marker/index.html).
It cannot help in some cases (when you need to annotate java sources, for example) - and here `@Deprecated` is used. But try `DslMarker` first.

```
@DslMarker
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS, AnnotationTarget.TYPE)
annotation class Scope

@Scope
class Outer {
    fun middle(op: Middle.() -> Unit): Middle { /**/ }
}

@Scope
class Middle {
    fun inner(op: Inner.() -> Unit): Inner {/**/ }
}

class Inner
```

Thus the last *middle* call is not compilable anymore.