# Is it possible to hide variables from lambda's closure?

Tags: lambda, kotlin, type-safety, builder-pattern

I'm trying to crate a type-safe groovy-style builder in Kotlin like it's described [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-safe-builders.html).
The problem is visibility of lambda receivers in nested lambdas.
Here is a simple example.

```
html {
    head(id = "head1")
    body() {
        head(id = "head2")
    }
}
```

Receiver of the nested lambda is Body that doesn't have the 'head' method. Nevertheless this code compiles and prints into this:

```
<html>
    <head id="head1"></head>
    <head id="head2"></head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

It is expected but is there any way to get compilation error on the inner head?

Comment: There is a workaround if you would like: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37000303/2094298

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Kotlin 1.0 this is not possible. There is an [open feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11551) for this functionality.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible since Kotlin 1.1, thanks to the [introduction of the `@DslMarker` annotation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew11.html#scope-control-for-implicit-receivers-in-dsls).

Here's an example of how it can be used:

```
@DslMarker
annotation class MyHtmlDsl

@MyHtmlDsl
class HeadBuilder

@MyHtmlDsl
class BodyBuilder

@MyHtmlDsl
class HtmlBuilder {
    fun head(setup: HeadBuilder.() -> Unit) {}
    fun body(setup: BodyBuilder.() -> Unit) {}
}

fun html(setup: HtmlBuilder.() -> Unit) {}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    html {
        head {}
        body {
            head { } // fun head(...) can't be called in this context by implicit receiver
        }
    }
}
```

See also the documentation at the announcement linked above.